# Run generated .py files without python installation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coding a `PyQt5` based GUI application needs to be able to create and run arbitrary Python scripts at runtime. If I convert this application to  a `.exe`, the main GUI Window will run properly. However, I do not know how I can run the short `.py` scripts that my application creates. Is it possible to runs these without a system wide Python installation?

> I don't want ways to compile my python application to exe. This problem relates to generated `.py` scripts

Comment: @Andrew, please clarify your question. As you can see people think you are asking about turning a Python project to an `.exe`

Comment: BTW, what does the main application create Python scripts for, instead of running the code they contain directly?

Comment: Just curious about knowing other ways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,  it won't work.  But you can make a small tool that will load the scripts and eval them within the context of packed executable. Look [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) for more details.  One thing to be mindful of is that your eval executable should import all the dependencies needed by your generated .py files

Comment: So that sounds better than the other answers here. I also heard that using ```eval``` is harmful or dangerous sometimes. Is it really that or I heard it wrong @Vlad

Comment: @AndrewWhiteman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Comment: So what to use then except eval @Tomerikoo

Comment: @AndrewWhiteman I think that's pracically your question, not something to answer in a comment

Answer (score 2):

No, to run a Python file you need an interpreter.

It is possible that your main application can contain a Python interpreter so that you don't need to depend on a system-wide Python installation.

Comment: Woah well how to do that? Is it even possible??

Comment: Yes, as I said it is possible. *How* to do this exactly, I can't explain here (I would have to research it myself, and it depends on your use case).